# Разработка на Unity?

Tags: unity3d, typescript

Всем привет! Я заинтересовался разработкой на Unity. И слышал что можно писать в нём на TypeScript, правда ли это, и если да то как это можно реализовать? Ибо по умолчанию там C#. Сам пишу на JS, долгое время, если это реально то ознакомлюсь с юнити через тайпскрипт а затем если мне понравится эта сфера начну учить C#. Давно интересует это, надеюсь что мне дадут здесь ответ.

Answer (score 1):

В Unity использовался собственный язык `UnityScript`, основанный на JavaScript.
Однако данный язык признан устаревшим. Написание новых проектов на нем не рекомендовано. Так что теперь только C# :)

Запись в блоге Unity: https://blog.unity.com/technology/unityscript-to-c-conversion-tool

Comment: Жаль, но если особых знаний UnityScript не нужно, просто попробовать чёт написать думаю можно)